# Запустить emacs для prolog

Tags: debian, prolog, emacs

Emacs воспринимает файлы с расширением `.pl`, как Perl. Как можно переключить его на Prolog? Пробовал записывать в файл `prolog.el` следующее:

```
(autoload 'run-prolog "prolog" "Start a Prolog sub-process." t)
(autoload 'prolog-mode "prolog" "Major mode for editing Prolog programs." t)
(autoload 'mercury-mode "prolog" "Major mode for editing Mercury programs." t)
(setq prolog-system 'swi)
(setq auto-mode-alist (append '(("\\.pl$" . prolog-mode)
                                ("\\.m$" . mercury-mode))
                               auto-mode-alist)
```

Не помогло.

Answer (score 1):

> Emacs воспринимает файлы с расширением `.pl`, как Perl.
>   Как можно переключить его на Prolog?

фрагмент документации c сайта SWI-Prolog:

**Using the PceEmacs built-in editor**
                  ...

**3.4.2.1 Edit modes**
                  ...

*Using the proper extension*

If the file ends in `.pl` or the selected alternative (e.g. `.pro`) extension, Prolog mode is selected.

*Using #!/path/to/.../swipl*

If the file is a Prolog Script file, starting with the line `#!/path/to/swipl options`, Prolog mode is selected regardless of the extension.

*Using -*- Prolog -*-*

If the above sequence appears in the first line of the file (inside a Prolog *comment*) Prolog mode is selected.

*Explicit selection*

Finally, using File/Mode/Prolog you can switch to Prolog mode explicitly.

Источник: http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=pceemacs